# Is there a way to get all tags related to a photo using Unsplash API?

Tags: node.js, api, photos

I understand that I can search by tag so I can find all photos that have been tagged to contain the term "dog" for example, but is there a way to get the photo and all its related tags (dog,puppy,backyard,etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the endpoint `GET /photos/:id` you are able to retrieve the `categories` of the photo.

```
"categories": [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Nature",
    "photo_count": 24783,
    "links": {
      "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/categories/4",
      "photos": "https://api.unsplash.com/categories/4/photos"
    }
  },
  // and so on
],
```

Comment: So the categories are the tags? For example this array would include a similar object for all the other keywords that describe the photo?

Comment: After reviewing, categories are actually **not** the tags. There is no mention of those in the documentation and also don't show up on any request, so it seems like they're not integrated in the API yet. But you could  add an issue on Github and let them know: https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js/issues

Comment: Oh thanks! I kept looking and I also found nothing, so I'll wait for them to add this option.